# Using Google Drive shared links in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api

I have found a lot of stuff online that shows how to access google drive with an account ID, etc.  I am trying to use my account in the website and don't want people to be able to see my account info by using inspect element.  I figured using a shared google drive link could work.... but then realized I could find nothing on how to make that work.

So, I would like to know if it's even possible to get information from this link.

If not, would it be better to make a new google account that I don't care if people get into?

Or, is their some kind of free cloud storage I could be using instead of drive?

Thanks, 
Lucas.

P.S. if it possible to use google drive to store cloud storage, does anyone know a good noobie-guide?  Everything I have found online is a little more advanced then I know.

P.P.S. I can't do any server-side stuff yet because I don't have my site hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Brief Disclaimer: *in beginning stages of learning javascript/coding*

### Making Your Page Safe:

If you are using NodeJS you can apply Passport to make sure that people working on the page are meant to be there and set up different routes so that certain areas are protected.  There are a few great tutorials on Scotch.io that go through the process of setting up Passport on your app.

Then there is this [Easy Node Authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-google) which rolls in how to integrate Passport with a google app and interact with their API in the process.  *Haven't gone through this specific tutorial.  Have done several tutorials on Scotch.io.  It is a great resource.*

### Interacting with Google Drive through your App:

[Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/) looks like it might be a step in the right direction.  They have some built-in methods and information on how to use them.

Hope that helps. :)